# Overwrites array elements from different controller [Codeigniter]

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, controller

I'm new to codeigniter.

I created two controllers, App and EmailController, my purpose is to change an element array `$date["subject"]` or others elements from App Controller.

```
include APPPATH.'controllers/EmailController.php';

class App extends EmailController {

    function index() {

        $sender = $this->input->post('sender');

        $data = $this->data;

        if($sender == 1)
        {
          $data["subject"] = "Sender One";
          file_get_contents(site_url('emailcontroller/send'));  
        }
        if($sender == 2) 
        {
          $data["subject"] = "Sender Two";
          file_get_contents(site_url('emailcontroller/send'));          
        } else
        {
          file_get_contents(site_url('emailcontroller/send'));      
        }
    }

}
```

This my EmailController:

```
class EmailController extends CI_Controller {

    var $data;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); 

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->data = array(
            'from_name' => 'Default Sender',
            'to' => 'default@email.com',
            'subject' => 'Default Subject' //use default subject if $sender is not 1 or 2
        );
    }   

    public function send() {

        $data = $this->data;
        ...    
        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($data['subject']);
        ....
    }
```

Thanks for advance!

Comment: `$this->data["subject"] = "Sender One";`

Comment: Doesn't work, email subject sent is 'Default Sender' again

Comment: Couple things why this doesn't work firstly, the __construct() function is the first thing to be called when the controller is accessed. So it's immediately overwriting the $this->data variable.

Secondly, you can't just pass data from one controller to another its isolated to each controller. However, you can store the data in the session and then access it in another controller. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Ok thanks, resolved with session method.